# Derivative amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, button

I want to handle 8 and more buttons or switches with only a few MCU pins and receive interrupt whenever some of the buttons is pressed (even if some switches are active).

I'd like to use PISO shift register to read data from buttons and switches and place voltage dividers with different output voltages on each button (shown at image below). Output of all voltage dividers will be connected to the derivative amplifier which should register any voltage change whenever any button is pressed.

Because more then one button can be pressed at the same time and supply voltage for voltage dividers will be 3.3 V, I'll need to detect voltage change less then 0.3 V, but when I make derivative amplifier with bigger gain, I have a large noise (i have negative voltage source for op amp made by inversing charge pump - image below - is possible that the noise is generated here?).

I would like to help with choosing components values for derivative amplifier for the smallest noise and the bigger gain.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**update:**
Thank you all for your suggestions. You have right about circuit complexity, so continuous checking of buttons state will be the best way.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use analog voltages to communicate something digital like button presses. Just concatenate enough PISOs to have one input for every button, and regularly read out as many bits serially as your PISOs have. What would be the problem with that?

Comment: Because I need to get an interrupt whenever any of button is pressed. Otherwise I would have to read serial data from PISOs all the time, which will consume a lot of processing time.

Comment: Use an 8 input AND gate (or OR gate) to feed the interrupt pin. Then read the PISO to see which switch was pressed.

Comment: I like Brian's approach. Also, all my microcontrollers have SPI units which I can simply ask to give me 8 or 16 bits of serial data, at zero CPU expense, and just compare the result to the previous one (typically, a single-cycle op). Also, if these are physical buttons, how often does it even make sense to know their state? It's not going to change on a millisecond scale. Are you sure this is going to use up any significant CPU time?

Comment: I have thinked about OR gates too, but there will be problem if any of  buttons will be pressed for a longer time and meantime  other button will be pressed too. Then the second button will not be reported.

Comment: If this wouldn't be possible I'll return to the simple checking of buttons values. I was just interested if there is some easy solution for this problem.

Comment: Nearly every time I price out the trade between external logic and a small microcontroller vs. a bigger microcontroller, the bigger microcontroller wins.  For me, the easy solution is usually to just use a processor with more pins.  At the next level down, consider how seldom you need to scan the buttons (they are running at human speed, yes?) and how little processor overhead a scan will take, particularly if you can use an SPI port.  Is it worth the board space to arrange for an interrupt?

Comment: I'd suggest rather than a complex solution such as you present it would be better to simply employ a small MCU for the task. An ATTiny84, 2313 or 4313 cost less than $1 and you could provide I2C and an interrupt and either scan or sense each switch individually and do bounce detection and do N-key rollover. All without impacting your main MCU code. Why build complex fixed purpose logic solutions when you don't have to.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments about unnecessary complexity. On the other side, practically aside, I like the ingenuity of your original idea. I suspect you would have horrible problems with key bouncing going through a differentiator (you would need to use a capacitor for debouncing purposes). In the same line of "why make it simple if you can complicate it", you could also use an ADC and figure out which button was pressed based on voltage. Have fun!

Comment: @Lucas  (1) Are your buttons pressed by a human?  Why do you want (or need?) to handle the buttons and switches with interrupts?  (2) Be advised that there are I/O expanders which generate interrupt on change.  Different models connect to MCU through SPI or I2C.